# Property [] of class [] can not be null error in Grails

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails and getting this error on two out of my three domains when I run the project on all the domains content.  The domain the works is

```
class Location {

    def scaffold = true


    String company 
    String name 
    String address
    static belongsTo=[company:Company]

    static constraints = {

}

}
```

The domain that does not work is

```
class Report {

    def scaffold = true

    String   title
    String   location 
    Date     published

    static belongsTo=[location:Location]

    static constraints = {

}
}
```

I can not see the structural or syntax issue that is trowing the errors.  I have been trying a variety of adds and subtracts and can not seem to find anything that address this error at a basic level.  Again I have just started using Grails and Groovy

Comment: When does the error occur? What does it exactly says?

Comment: When I click Create I get-----                                          Create Report
Property [location] of class [class lcm.Report] cannot be null
Property [published] of class [class lcm.Report] cannot be null
Property [title] of class [class lcm.Report] cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the changes told by @araxn1d, you should also check the constraints. By default all properties are not nullable (that's why you're getting for example the error for the title property)

If you already have data in your database you have two options:

1. Update your database and set the correct values in each table or row
2. Set each property in the domain as nullable. For example

   static constraints = {
       title nullable:true
   }

Comment: I just tried adding the {nullable:true} and got this error----URI
/lcm/report/list
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: lcm.Report.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: list(), list(java.util.Map), last(), last(java.lang.String), last(java.util.Map), first()------The database is blank I want the user to be able to enter the data

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean and re-run the app? This error sometimes happens to me when I change a domain class, but doing a clean and running again the app works

Comment: It should be { propertyName nullable: true }, you're missing the name, i.e. you have to do that for *every* nullable property. See my answer for more information.

Comment: Tried all of it and still get the same error and now I also get an error on the Location class saying that there is a problem with the name field error is as follows---Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type lcm.Company for property company; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [lcm.Company] for property company: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: that last error is because you have set company as a String, but you also have belongsTo=[company:Company]. company can't be a String and a Company class... Just delete String company to get rid of that error

Comment: I got that fixed and then moved my scaffolding to the Controller and Viola it works.  Thanks for all of our help

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a Report with no properties set? By default, Grails will check that all properties are not null. If you want to allow the user to leave a certain field undefined (null), then you have to explicitly tell Grails in the [constraints map](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html):

```
static constraints = {
  propertyName nullable: true
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not fix the issue.  I even tried the syntax of propertyName (nullable:true)  with no luck and after making the changes araxn1d suggested I get the error-- Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type lcm.Company for property company; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [lcm.Company] for property company: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Well, you have another class called lcm.Company and your "company" property is a String. If you are setting the property to a lcm.Company value, then it will not work (Groovy will not know how to convert a lcm.Company into a String, that's the error you're getting). Change the types and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like error is in this line:

```
String location
```

**location** is `String` type, but should be `Location`type. The same as `String company` in Location domain should be `Company company`.

Comment: Made the changes and I am still getting the same errors                 Create Report
Property [location] of class [class lcm.Report] cannot be null
Property [published] of class [class lcm.Report] cannot be null
Property [title] of class [class lcm.Report] cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've changed the structure of the domain class after you generated the automatically created views/controller for the domain.

I fixed it by just deleting the offending domain along with the controller/views file and recreating them.  I'm sure you could root through and find the offending code though.